# How to use variables already defined in ConfigParser

Tags: python, configparser

I'm using ConfigParser in Python

config.ini is

```
[general]
name: my_name
base_dir: /home/myhome/exp

exe_dir: ${base_dir}/bin
```

Here I want `exp_dir` becomes `/home/myhome/exp/bin` not `${base_dir}/bin`.

It means `${base_dir}` would be substituted to `/home/myhome/exp automatically`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) interpolation

> On top of the core functionality,
>   SafeConfigParser supports
>   interpolation. This means values can
>   contain format strings which refer to
>   other values in the same section, or
>   values in a special DEFAULT section.
>   Additional defaults can be provided on
>   initialization.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> [My Section] 
> foodir: %(dir)s/whatever 
> dir=frob 
> long: this value continues    
>     in the next line
> ```
>
> would resolve the %(dir)s to the value
>   of dir (frob in this case). All
>   reference expansions are done on
>   demand.

Your example becomes:

```
[general]
name: my_name
base_dir: /home/myhome/exp

exe_dir: %(base_dir)s/bin
```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of "${foo}", write "%(foo)s". (See http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html and search for "interpolation". This works for either an ordinary ConfigParser or a SafeConfigParser.)

Comment: Thanks! In my code, the missing `s` after the `%(foo)` drove me crazy. Sometimes you've got to look at the source first, before you realize it's in the docs, too! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3, you can use `${base_dir}/bin`, and the [extended interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ExtendedInterpolation) allows you to use variables from other sections. Example:

```
[Common]
home_dir: /Users
library_dir: /Library
system_dir: /System
macports_dir: /opt/local

[Frameworks]
Python: 3.2
path: ${Common:system_dir}/Library/Frameworks/

[Arthur]
nickname: Two Sheds
last_name: Jackson
my_dir: ${Common:home_dir}/twosheds
my_pictures: ${my_dir}/Pictures
python_dir: ${Frameworks:path}/Python/Versions/${Frameworks:Python}
```

Comment: `configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())`