# How to refer to a value from a different section in python config file?

Tags: python, config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use variables already defined in ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999190/how-to-use-variables-already-defined-in-configparser)

For example, I have the following config file:

```
[Sec1]
opt1 = 1

[Sec2]
opt2 = 1
```

I want to set `opt2` equal to `opt1` explicitly, so that if I update `opt1` later, `opt2` will be updated as well.

But I cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: Duplicate of [4999190](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4999190/). Unfortunately the answer is: reference expansion only works inside the same section, not across sections.

Answer (score 2):

You can use interpolation with either `ConfigParser` or `SafeConfigParser`. However, you cannot interpolate between sections in the configuration, unless one of them is `DEFAULT`:

```
[DEFAULT]
opt1 = 1

[Sec2]
opt2 = %(opt1)s
```

It's important to note that the `DEFAULT` options mask any further attempt to use them in other sections, and that you cannot re-assign `opt1` via `Sec2.opt2`.